# What are sentences like "the longer X, the more Y" called and can they be used in formal written English?

Tags: terminology, formality, writing, register, correlative-comparatives

What is the type of sentence exemplified below called? Is it appropriate to use it in a scientific paper and formal written English in general?

> **1.** The more pronounced the variation, the
>   more the waste.
>
> **2.** The more you give, the more you get.
>
> **3.** The longer I live, the more I realize the impact of attitude on life.

Comment: Looks like a "comparative correlative". There are various names for similar parallel constructions. See http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/Comparative-Correlatives.htm

Comment: It's called an Idiomatic Construction. This particular one has no special name, but you could call it _The sooner the better construction_, with a common example, and it'd be recognized by any grammarian. Constructions are like multi-word idioms, with required words or grammar (here the comparative is required on both sides, but no subject or verb is required).

Comment: ... and I found when I looked, as usual, that [I had already commented on this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/521426/15299).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know if there's a name for such sentences themselves, but they are surely appropriate in formal English:

- [Bible search results for "the more"](http://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=%22the+more%22&qs_version=NIV). Here are only some of the various possible syntactical structures:

  > - But **the more they were oppressed, the more they multiplied** and spread; so the Egyptians came to dread the Israelites. (Exodus 1:12)
  > - For with much wisdom comes much sorrow; **the more knowledge, the more grief**. (Ecclesiastes 1:18)
  > - **The more priests there were, the more they sinned** against me; they exchanged their glorious God for something disgraceful. (Hosea 4:7)
- [British National Corpus search results for "the more"](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=the+more&mysubmit=Go). Again, just a couple examples:

  > - **The higher** the Péclet number, **the more contorted** the pattern must become before this happens.
  > - **The more correct** the early stages of training, **the less chance there is** of things going wrong.
  > - **[T]he more I worked** on it **the more it began** to evolve into another kind of idea **and the more removed it became** from my initial study which had so much freedom and energy, so I stopped.
  > - Crudely, **the more effort** involved in processing a metaphor, **the "better", or the more poetic**, the metaphor is supposed to be.

Wiktionary [says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the#Adverb):

> **Adverb**
>
> **1.** With a comparative or *more* and a verb phrase, establishes a parallel with one or more other such comparatives.
>
> - The hotter, the better.
> - The more I think about it, the weaker it looks.
> - The more money donated, the more books purchased and the more happy children.
> - It looks weaker and weaker, the more I think about it.
>
> **2.** With a comparative, and often with *for it*, indicates a result more like said comparative. This can be negated with *none*.
>
> - It was a difficult time, but I’m the wiser for it.
> - It was a difficult time, and I’m none the wiser for it.
> - I'm much the wiser for having had a difficult time like that.

The corresponding Merriam-Webster entry reads [as follows](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the?show=1&t=1286875332):

> **1** : than before : than otherwise —used before a comparative <none *the* wiser for attending>
>   **2 a** : to what extent <*the* sooner the better>
>      **b** : to that extent <the sooner *the* better>

Do note that — as the third Wiktionary example and the last two of the BNC examples quoted above demonstrate — the chain is not limited to just two items. In fact, there is no theoretical limit, only a practical one that depends entirely on context.

Also (and this is addressed by both Merriam-Webster and Wiktionary, but I think I should expressly state it here), this *the* is etymologically not the same as the article *the*. The article comes from Old English *þē*, a variant of *sē*, while the adverb comes from Old English *þȳ*, the instrumental case of *sē* and *þæt*. If we look at related languages, e.g. German where the article would be *der*, the construction "the more, the better" is still formed with a different word even today: "je mehr, je besser" (or "je mehr, desto besser"). Follow the Wiktionary link for more infos.

This construction is not limited to Germanic languages, either. Russian has "чем... тем...". French has "plus... plus...". A fellow poster provides additional information in his [answer to a related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9660/could-you-help-me-to-do-a-syntax-analysis-of-this-sentence/9666#9666). He also simply and elegantly calls this construction the "parallel comparative", which is not a term I've used before, but one that is conveniently self-explanatory.

Comment: Why is it allowed that some of the clauses don't have subjects or predicates? (e.g., The hotter the better.)

Comment: Presumably because the subject is generally clear given the context. That said, you certainly can add subjects in: the hotter the pepper, the better [it tastes]

Answer (score 6):

It is called **comparative correlative** or **conditional comparative**:

> In grammar, a *comparative correlative* is a minor sentence pattern
>   containing two corresponding phrases or clauses, each one headed by the and 
>   expressing a comparative: *the X-er . . . the X-er or the X-er . . . the Y-er.*
>
> The comparative correlative is also known as the *correlative construction*, 
>   the *conditional comparative*, or the *"the . . . the" construction*.
>
> Grammatically, the comparative correlative is a type of paired 
>   construction; rhetorically, the comparative correlative is often (but not 
>   always) a type of parison.

http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/Comparative-Correlatives.htm

Answer (score 5):

I think that what you're looking for is covered by the concept of parallelism.  There are a number of rhetorical devices that use parallel structures to provide emphasis to a relationship; [Anaphora](http://www.americanrhetoric.com/figures/anaphora.htm) is one that looks promising as a formal term.

It's my opinion that it's very much valid to use in formal english, especially as it has a greek name attached and is a formal rhetorical structure ;-P

Comment: It's ordinary, literal English, not a figure of speech.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a special name, but I know where I find it in grammars: in the chapter Adjectives and there under comparative forms. The better, the more expensive or in full form The better something is the more expensive it is - such structures are used in spoken and written language. I think mathematicians call such a relation between two values proportion or direct proportion and one might use the term proportionality.
But grammars normally don't use a special name. You find it in the box "comparison".

Answer (score -2):

Such type of sentences can't be classified as simple cause there are two finite verb ,can't be classified as complex as there is no principal clause .Again they are not compound sentence.They are just traditional quote or proverbs.

Comment: They are not, by definition, 'Traditional quotes or proverbs'. As [the accepted answer states](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3945/194281), *6 years ago*, they are adverbs. sometimes the construction is used in quotes and proverbs, but [correlation does not mean causation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation).