# What is the etymology of "the"?

Tags: etymology, articles, definite-articles

I was just having this conversation with a friend. Where does the word "the" come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me introduce you to the wonderful site that is [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=the&searchmode=none):

> late O.E. *þe*, nominative masculine form of the demonstrative pronoun and adjective. After c.950, it replaced earlier *se* (masc.), *seo* (fem.), *þæt* (neut.), and probably represents *se* altered by the *þ-* form which was used in all the masc. oblique cases (see below). O.E. *se* is from [[Proto-Indo-European](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language)] base **so-* "this, that" (cf. Skt. *sa*, Avestan *ha*, Gk. *ho*, *he* "the," Ir., Gael. *so* "this"). For the *þ-* forms, see *that*. The *s-* forms were entirely superseded in English by mid-13c., excepting dialectal survival slightly longer in Kent. O.E. used 10 different words for "the" (see table, below), but did not distinguish "the" from "that." *That* survived for a time as a definite article before vowels (cf. *that one* or *that other*). Adv. use in *the more the merrier*, *the sooner the better*, etc. is a relic of O.E. *þy*, originally the instrumentive case of the neuter demonstrative *þæt* (see *that*).

See also my comment on this related question: [How are sentences like “the longer X, the more Y” called and can they be used in formal written English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/how-are-sentences-like-the-longer-x-the-more-y-called-and-can-they-be-used-in/3945#3945)

Answer (score 2):

The and that are common developments from the Old English system. Old English had a definite article se, in the masculine gender, seo (feminine), and þæt (neuter). In Middle English these had all merged into þe, the ancestor of the Modern English word the.