# Use of definite article in "the more" and "the less"

Tags: articles, definite-articles, correlative-comparatives

Why is the definite article used in expressions like *the more* and *the less*? For example,

> The more you study, the more you know.
>
> The less you study, the less you know.

Comment: Related: [What are sentences like “the longer X, the more Y” called and can they be used in formal written English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3944/what-are-sentences-like-the-longer-x-the-more-y-called-and-can-they-be-used-i)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not really the definite article, it just looks like the definite article. It's derived from the instrumental case form of the pronoun *that* in Anglo-Saxon (meaning "by that amount"), which has come to be pronounced exactly the same as the definite article over the centuries.