# Is my syntax correct and is there a better version?

Tags: grammaticality, questions, correlative-comparatives

Here is the sentence:
"Why is a conjugated system bigger, the smaller the atomic electron transitions?"
I mean that when a conjugated system gets bigger, the atomic electron transitions get smaller, and I want to know why is that.
Thank you :)

Comment: While writing advice may be off topic, the structural and semantic errors are likely relevant on this site.

Comment: You've already essentially provided your own syntax. If you combine your two sentences and add two words, here is what you wrote: *Why is it that when a conjugated system gets bigger, the atomic electron transitions get smaller?*

Answer (score -1):

"Why is a conjugated system bigger, the smaller the atomic electron transitions?"

In the usual structure of "[comparative correlative](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-comparative-correlative-grammar-1689769)" type of parallelism it would be:

> Why is it that the bigger the conjugated system, the smaller the atomic electron transitions?

**Note the inversion.**

HTH.

*See also:*
ELU: [What are sentences like “the longer X, the more Y” called and can they be used in formal written English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3944/14666)
EnglishGrammar: ["The…the… with comparative adjectives"](https://www.englishgrammar.org/thethe-comparative-adjectives/)